# AccessDenied when calling the GenerateServiceLastAccessedDetails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

The role I am assuming has the `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/SecurityAudit` policy attached which includes the necessary permissions

```
"iam:GenerateServiceLastAccessedDetails",
"iam:Get*",
"iam:List*"
```

On Resource `*`. And yet I still get `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GenerateServiceLastAccessedDetails operation: User: <assumed_role> is not authorized to perform the operation on <role_arn>`. Is it a bug in AWS?

Answer (score 0):

I found that this occurs when the arn in the request is invalid. The error message is a bug, it is an invalid input, not an access denied issue.